# how to count number usage of a tag? django with taggableManager

Tags: django, count, tags

I am currently using `taggableManager` as my tags in `django`.  I can see in admin what is currently using the tag but then is there a way to count them?

let's say I have the follow tag and as can see there are a 4 objects using this tag.  how can I get the count of 4 for this tag?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will want to do a typical query on your database for the count of rows for a particular tag.  Instead of looking at the len of a queryset there is another count feature less commonly known in Django which gives you the count number from SQL as opposed to having to query the entire database just to get the length.

> len(). A QuerySet is evaluated when you call len() on it. This, as you
>   might expect, returns the length of the result list.
>
> Note: If you only need to determine the number of records in the set
>   (and don’t need the actual objects), it’s much more efficient to
>   handle a count at the database level using SQL’s SELECT COUNT(*).
>   Django provides a count() method for precisely this reason.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: I am not looking to count all the rows though.
let me take a ss of my admin, might help me explain better